# if,else how to write a math quit

Tags: if-statement

i want to write a math test
EX:i input a right number,then i can get point.
finally,i can get the total score.
there is my attempt.
but,when i input a wrong number,i always get point.
what should i do?

```
char a;
int b;
char d;     
b=0;

printf("1+1=\n");    
a=getchar();    
if(a=2){ 
    printf("you got%d \n",b=b+10);
}else{ 
    printf("you got%d \n",b);
}

printf("1+2=\n");    
d=getchar();
if(d=3){ 
    printf("you got%d \n",b=b+10);
}else{ 
    printf("you got%d \n",b);
} 

return 0;
```

Comment: Looks like C. Change `if(a=2)` to `if(a==2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `if (a == '2')` rather than `if (a=2)`.

The former:

- tests the value of `a`, unlike the latter which assigns `a`
- compares `a` with the character '2', rather than the number 2.

Comment: i use 'if (a==2)' but i input right number,i do not get point

Comment: Yep, I've revised the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to compare in the If statement, then you should use comparison operator **`==`** and not assignment operator **`=`**. 
Also if you're comparing characters , you need to use character quotes **`''`**

Eg.

```
if(a=='2')
{
 printf("you got%d \n",b=b+10);
}
```